# Is it possible to create a new solution from an existing directory with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have a directory generated from yeoman's "yo aspnet" that I'd like to edit in Xamarin. Is it possible to create a Xamarin solution from these existing files? Is there a way to import directory created by yeoman into Xamarin for editing?

Comment: I found the answer here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/76707/xs-can-no-longer-add-an-existing-file-to-project-after-upgrade-to-6-0-2. Just ctrl click on the project. The context menu gives several options. The option that I was after was "Add Existing Folder."

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/76707/xs-can-no-longer-add-an-existing-file-to-project-after-upgrade-to-6-0-2.

Just control-click on the project. The context menu gives several options. The option that I was after was "Add Existing Folder."

Thanks,
John